# SharePoint not populating columns

Tags: 2007, list, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

My company is using the 3.0 version of sharepoint. I designed a form on InfoPath Designer 2010 and published as a form library on SharePoint. When I published the form I set all the cloumns needed for the SharePoint view in the Publishing Wizard. The People/Group pickers would populate correctly on the view and a few days later would lose the info. I republished the form and double checked that the People/Group field selected from InfoPath was correct, named correctly, set as  (None: Create newcolumn in this library) like before and set to merge because we use mulitple contacts in the field.
When I run a test form after republishing all the columns populate but when I click on a form that was already submitted and resubmit the People/Group pickers will not repopulate even when I manually reenter the information. What would cause this problem and how do I fix it?
I am not writing this form using code

Answer (score 0):

Where have you found People/Group Picker? In Infopath 2010 I manage to see only Person/Group Picker.
What do you mean under "When I published the form I set all the cloumns needed for the SharePoint view in the Publishing Wizard"? I do not understand what (how and why) are "all columns" needed and how did you set them in Publishing Wizard.   Why do you tag a question on Infopath 2010 by "2007"?
Also, merging forms has nothing to do with necessity to have multiple contacts in the field. Which forms, how and why did you merge?

So, if you need to insert multiple contacts, then republish the form without choosing merge options and insert multiple contacts